# IIS7 Windows 2008 R2 w3wp.exe not releasing memory

Tags: asp.net, windows, web-services, iis-7.5, w3wp

So we are running a ASP.NET web service on a Windows 2008 R2 production server runing IIS 7 with latest updates. Of late we noticed that there was high memory consumption.

After implementing garbage disposal techniques, memory seems to be very much under control. However when the Application Pool (w3wp.exe) recycles after the specified time, the memory it had taken up to that point is not released back to the system. If we recycle manually, the same phenomena is observed and memory consumed to that point seems to be lost.

New w3wp.exe instance is seen in Task Manager with low memory usage @ few hundred MB but the System memory keeps rising to unreasonable levels.

We have a 32 gig server and within a few days this reaches 20-25GB used memory and machine becomes sluggish. Only a complete Windows reboot seems to work.

Any insights as to why memory is not released even after the application pool is terminated would be helpful. Where can we look?

DebugDiag tells nothing abnormal even after large scans. Also, unable to get stack dumps from DebugDiag.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please specify what memory you are talking about. If its virtual memory, then it is independent of RAM.

If you are observing high system memory and not high w3wp memory after making code changes, then I don't think the problem lies within w3wp. Also, since a reboot of server resolves the issue, I dont think w3wp is the culprit here.

If you are under the assumption that when the application pool recycles, the memory it occupied can be used by other, it would be incorrect. Each process runs independently and within its own virtual space.

For example, 32 bit application on a 32 bit machine can crawl up to 4 GB virtual memory ( 2 GB user-mode and 2 GB kernel-mode). 32 bit application on a 64 bit machine can crawl upto 8GB (4GB user-mode and 4 GB kernel mode). 64 bit app on a 64 bit machine can crawl upto 8 TB (4TB user-mode and 4 TB kernel-mode). And this is completely independent of your RAM.

For your situation, certain things that you can try.

1. Disable all third party services and check the behavior.
2. Observe the component (process) that takes up highest memory when the overall system is at high memory
3. Capture perfmon to understand what exactly is happening internally.
4. I think you may have to take a dump of the overall system and then identify what's going on. ( I am not an expert at this)

Please let me know if you have any follow up questions.